# How is Javascript Date handled in other languages?

Tags: javascript, date

I don't have the liberty of testing my Javascript on a foreign operating system. I would like to know if the following will work globally:

```
var d = new Date(
   'Tue Aug 20 2011 16:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)'
);
```

If a Spanish OS were to run this, would it crash? Would I have to use this instead?

```
var d = new Date(
   'Mar Ago 20 2011 16:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacífico Hora de verano)'
);
```

I use strings to initialize Date because I hate using the numerical approaches which all require translating into UTC.

Comment: What about non-Latin alphabets? E.g. Cyrillic or Hebrew?

Comment: You honestly prefer adding "GMT-0700" and a bunch of other stuff, greatly decreasing efficiency, over adding a single ` - 7 + 24) % 24`?

Comment: I copied and pasted that date string from `new Date().toString()`. No hard labor was done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The string format is strict about language. English only. I have a Hebrew OS and I use English just fine. (Trying Hebrew crashes it).

Comment: Is your browser set to Hebrew too? The browser's language may override the OS's setting.